# Why are there so many SessionFactoryImpl objects in the dump?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jprofiler

I have ~15,000 identical SessionFactoryImpl objects in my dump:

[image]

One of the objects with incoming references:

[image]

One of the objects with outbound references:

[image]

I don't have the following parameters configured and they are set by default accordingly:

```
hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_size
hibernate.query.plan_parameter_metadata_max_size
```

Questions:

1. Why are there so many SessionFactoryImpl objects and why aren't they
   deleted?
2. Are they created incorrectly somewhere in the code, or is it due to
   unspecified caching parameters?
3. If so, what parameters should I set for caching?
4. Should I set any other settings?
5. If these objects are created in code, how can I find the class that
   creates these objects in Jprofiler?

Versions:

- Hibernate 5.4.3.Final
- Spring 5.1.6.RELEASE

Comment: They are there because they are created, which probably means you are doing things in your code you shouldn't be doing in the first place. The error is likely to be in your own code or how you think you should use Spring (in the wrong way).

Comment: With tools like [MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) you could have specific reports to analyze memory leaks (never used jprofiler, but it seems to provides similar feature like [STELLAR ANALYSIS OF MEMORY LEAKS](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)). Try to see a commond factor, in these queries, and find which part of your code could be the main cause of this problem.

Comment: *Why are there so many SessionFactoryImpl objects and why aren't they deleted?* Idk why but nor they should be deleted - singleton should be reused (as long as db config is not changing)

Comment: *If these objects are created in code, how can I find the class that creates these objects in Jprofiler?* JVisualm had and option to trace creation stacktraces - but that applies only  to the profiling runtime and not "historical creations" JProfiler will probably have something similar.

Comment: Try the "Merged dominating references" in the references view of the heap walker.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice, I'm still investigating this issue.

Comment: *f these objects are created in code, how can I find the class that creates these objects in Jprofiler?* How about using the debugger with a break point... #lowTechIsTheNewHighTech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the incorrectly implemented method of logging to the database. When a certain task was completed, factories for logging were always created, which had a reference to the SessionFactoryImpl. And there were many such tasks, and each time these factories were created. We were able to find this place in the code and fix it so that the log factory was created once when the application was launched.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can locate the code line number where the SessionFactoryImpl objects created by using the "Show Selection In Heap Walker " and watch the allocation tree of the objects in "Allocations"